# Cannot open source file "glad/gl.h" GLFW OPENGL

Tags: c++, glfw

It keeps showing this error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMY2U.png) I cannot figure out why, I am using VSCODE the newest version, here is my C/C++ Properties json: [c_cpp_properties.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYu5W.png) I have it set up all correctly according to tutorials. [files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eaCv.png)

I can't get rid of this error no matter how much I try,

Comment: Why are you posting text as images? Where is this `gl.h` file? Did you mean `#include <glad/glad.h>`?

Comment: No images of code or otherwise plain text here please!

Comment: Attention to detail is one of the most important qualities to be a programmer. Think about what happened here, you used the wrong file name, the compiler told you the file name could not be found. the image you posted demonstrated that the file name did not exist, and yet you could not figure it out. Now I'm sure you a smart guy, but all the information needed to figure out this puzzle was at your fingertips, so what went wrong? Every programmer makes silly mistakes, but they should be able to figure out what the mistake was.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the image you provided, there is no `glad/gl.h` in your project

are you sure you are looking for `<glad/gl.h>` and not `<glad/glad.h>` ?